# SVG: The blending of semitransparent lines is dependent on the stroke width?

Tags: html, svg, width, transparent, stroke

The blending of semitransparent lines on top of each other behaves differently depending on the used stroke width when viewed in Chrome or Firefox.

[Example](https://codepen.io/crocophant/pen/qBdWggL):

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" version="1.1">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 200 200 L 0 200 L 200 200 L 0 200 L 200 0" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.80" stroke-opacity="0.75" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
    </svg>
```

The line at the bottom is drawn three times on top of each other, therefore it should appear darker when blended. With a stroke width of <= 0.8, it behaves as expected. A width > 0.8 changes all lines to be uniform in color. Note that the behavior is also dependent on the zoom level used in the browser.

- `stroke-width="0.8"`

[image: width="0.80"]

- `stroke-width="0.81"`

[image: width="0.81"]

- `stroke-width="5"`

[image: width="5"]

The problem I'm facing is that I have a lot of overlapping semitransparent lines in my application and the resulting image should implicitly highlight which paths have been used more often than others ([Example in codepen](https://codepen.io/crocophant/pen/QWbLYzp)):

- correct with `stroke-width="0.8"`

[image: correct with width 0.8]

- wrong with `stroke-width="0.81"`

[image: wrong with width 0.81]

Is there any approach for correct blending? `shape-rendering` does have an influence, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You could try shape-rendering="crispEdges" to turn off anti-aliasing and see if that helps.

Comment: While "crispEdges" works with the given example, it doesn't work with my line rendering. Additionally, it shows different results in Firefox vs. Chrome. It makes it even worse in Firefox with stroke-width=0.8. I added an example for my line rendering in the original post.